# Is it safe to share my project in BigQuery with others(publicly)?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a project with more than 10 datasets and one dataset has more than 70 tables(tables created for beginner level and intermediate level). If I share my project publicly, my project name and project id will be exposed to many students. Is it safe to do like this? Will I be hacked or attacked by using the project name and project id by others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you only give the role [`dataViewer`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles), the people whom you shared the project with will only be able to get the data from your tables, not modify it or insert jobs (that's what actually has cost).

This will force users to use their own projects to run jobs querying your datasets.

However, I would suggest you not to share this completely publicly. If you're using G Suite in your school, or if you know the Google accounts (most likely Gmail) from your students, you should create a [Google group](https://groups.google.com/) with the people who requires the access, and then [giving permission to that group](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#google_group).

Comment: is it safe to give project read access role. On giving this role - public can use only select clause, they can't delete or create dataset in my project. am i correct? is it safe?